# Estilização de Select via CSS

Tags: css, html-select

Preciso estilizar o texto que há dentro do `select`, como deixar centralizado, colocar margens. Estou colocando o nome da classe mais `option` e colocando o que desejo, porém não está funcionando. Fiz assim:

HTML

```
<h3 class="imobBoxTipoTitulo">Tipo</h3>    
<div>
    <select class="imobBoxTipo">
       <option>Todos</option>
       <option>Teste1</option>
           <option>Teste2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="imobValor">
    <div class="imobValorEsq">
        <h3 class="imobBoxTipoTitulo">Valor</h3>
        <select class="imobBoxTipo imobBoxTipoValor">
           <option>De</option>
           <option>Teste1</option>
           <option>Teste2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="imobValorDir">
        <select class="imobBoxTipo imobBoxTipo">
           <option>At&eacute;</option>
           <option>Teste1</option>
           <option>Teste2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imobBoxTipoTitulo{font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 9px;font-weight: bold;color:#b8b8b8;text-transform: uppercase;}

.imobBoxTipo{
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
   height: 34px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(../images/arrow.jpg) no-repeat right #ddd;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
.imobBoxTipo select{
    width: 260px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif!important;   
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: transparent;
}
.imobBoxTipoValor{width: 110px;}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/3AK7V/)

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3942/como-fazer-para-estilizar-a-tag-select

Comment: E também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3827/como-forcar-que-os-elementos-option-aparecam-abaixo-do-select-no-ie/3828#3828

Comment: O que acontece é que a seta do select está ficando acima do background-image.
http://felipestoker.com/imob/

Comment: tem como você contornar isso criando uma div menor como pai do select e setando ela com uma background-image que tenha uma "setinha" - Porém Importante: deve ser menor o suficiente para que a seta original não apareça.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta acrescentar no css:

```
select{
  width: 250px;
   height: 50px;
   font-size: 20px;
   background: #f2f2f3;
   padding-left: 100px
}
```

No caso do `text-align: center` isso não funciona, para alinhar basta usar o `padding-left`.
E nos `options` ele receberam a formatação do `select` porém ficarão com o seu tamanho e outros requisitos padronizados pelo navegador.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Eu estou usando line-height para alinhar no centro também, porém não está funcionando.

Comment: Use o `padding-top`.

Comment: E tem como modificar a flecha que é criada automaticamente do select? conforme aqui http://felipestoker.com/imagens/img2.jpg

Comment: O único que eu achei foi utilizando `jquery`. Dá uma olhada:

Fonte: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/#.UGWhd03A_TA

Answer (score 0):

Para formatar um select não precisa de criar classes para cada uma delas, basta especificar a tag select ou option visto que elas têm inicio e fim em torno do conteúdo que se quer alterar. ex:. "< select > conteudo < / select> " o mesmo pode ser feito com uma tag "< p >< / p >".

```
select {
width:130px;
height:30px;
font-family:Verdana, Trebuchet,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
padding:5px;
background-color:#45675D;
//Recomenda-se deixar essa linha de fora, porque a formatação a esquerta a justificada nos select fica melhor.
padding-left:40px;
}

option {
background-color:#45765D;
}
```

Observe como fica: http://jsfiddle.net/3AK7V/6/

Comment: Edilson, se eu fizer isso, todos os selects e options ocuparam essas regras, não?

Comment: Sim vão ser afectadas, até porque normalmente não se utiliza selects com mais de 1 tipo de estilização na mesma página por questão de estilo mesmo. Nota seste exemplo aqui, alterando apenas a primeira div para id="isto" e passando os parâmetros para o css #isto >    select {} apenas o primeiro bloco é alterado, não sendo necessário a criação de várias classes: http://jsfiddle.net/3AK7V/7/