# Diferença de exibição de SELECT entre navegadores

Tags: css, google-chrome, select, firefox

Tenho o seguinte código `HTML` que marca um `SELECT`:

```
<select name="filtro">
  <option value="">Mais visualizados</option>
  <option value="">Menos visualizados</option>
  <option value="">Mais Recentes</option>
</select>
```

Dá este resultado no Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Detalhe ele só aplica o código CSS para o `OPTION` que carrega junto com a pagina. Os seguintes ele não estiliza com o mesmo `font-weight`, isto no Chrome. Segue o CSS:

```
.filtro select{
  font-family: Lato, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  left: 650px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
```

Já no Firefox ele apresenta isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com a propriedade `appearance` tento tirar a aparência da engine que está sendo usado no momento. Porém, isto só funcionou no Chrome. Já no Firefox ele aplica essa seta para baixo.

Alguém já passou por isso? Alguma solução?

Comment: Estilização de `<select>` e `<option>` varia mesmo de acordo com o navegador. A única solução garantida é criar seu próprio simulacro de select, usando divs, css e js (e de preferência usando um select oculto como fallback, garantindo acessibilidade, etc.)

Comment: Eu desisti de estilizar `<select>` e `<option>`, quando preciso de algo, procuro algum plugin.

Fiz uma pergunta parecida aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9487/estiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-select-via-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Tenta ver se acha algo legal que sirva pra seus requisitos de suporte a navegadores.

- http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-selectbox-plugin/

Alguns experimentos legais com select também, só precisa checar o suporte aos navegadores:

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/07/10/inspiration-for-custom-select-elements/
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/
- http://tympanus.net/Development/SimpleDropDownEffects/

Espero ter ajudado... =)