# Como estilizar, com CSS, um SELECT que está dentro do PHP?

Tags: php, css, select

```
<?php

    include "conexao.php";

    $sql = "select * from categorias";
    $dados = pg_query($sql);
    $resposta = "";

    while($linha = pg_fetch_array($dados)){
        $nome_categoria = $linha["nome_categoria"];
        $resposta .= "<option>".$nome_categoria."</option>";
    }

    $categoria = "<select>". $resposta."</select>";
    pg_free_result($dados);

?>
```

HTML

```
<tr><td><a class="itens">Categoria:</td>
<td><?php echo $categoria;?></a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Indaiara bem vinda ao stack overflow. O select ser gerado no php e a aplicação de estilos no mesmo são duas coisas distintas. Verifique se [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9487/estiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-select-via-css) já respondida não soluciona seu problema.

Comment: Então não teria como eu mudar a fonte dos resultados gerados no select??

Comment: Sua dúvida está em como aplicar o css a um elemento select/option, isso ?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como faço pra mudar a fonte do que é mostrado dentro de um select

Comment: Na pergunta que coloquei como link mostra como estilizar o select, basta alterar o css e alterar o `font-family`. Recomendo ler: [tour], [help] e [ask]

Comment: Sim, mas como faço pra chamar no CSS, já que o meu select está no PHP ?? Dá pra colocar uma classe no PHP ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O fato do select ser gerado pelo PHP não faz nenhuma diferença quanto à estilização do mesmo. Lembre-se, o seu script PHP está retornando HTML, que é interpretado no navegador.

Quanto à estilização, note que o elemento `select` pode ser estilizado mais livremente que os elementos `option`, que tem muitas de suas propriedades limitadas pelo navegador usado.

Para estilizar, você pode usar uma classe, um id ou a própria tag `select` (note que a última irá estilizar todos os `select`, o que pode ou não ser o desejado).

```
select {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Se desejar usar uma classe, coloque ela no seu PHP:

```
$categoria = "<select class='minha-classe'>". $resposta."</select>";
```

Depois no CSS:

```
select.minha-classe {
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: então como faço para chamar no CSS ?? Sou iniciante.. Obrigada..

Comment: Obrigada funcionou!!!