# Centralizar texto do select

Tags: css

Como centralizar o texto de um select? Eu removi as setas pra baixo com o

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Mas o texto fica ao lado e não centraliza. Fica assim:

```
--------------------------
|TEXTO DO SELECT         |
--------------------------
```

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

```
--------------------------
|    TEXTO DO SELECT     |
--------------------------
```

Ja tentei com text-align, com margin, etc e não fica. Por que?

---

## EDIT

Ate tentei com padding-left, da resposta do guilheme, mas mudando a resolução, da poblema. Teria outra solução?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Estilização de Select via CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9487/estiliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-select-via-css)

Comment: Na verdade não deu não, ele vai pro lado, mas mudando a resolução, da problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem a ajuda de plugins externos, você pode centralizar **somente o texto dentro da caixa** e não os do dropdown, colocando o seguinte CSS no `select`:

```
text-align: center; /* para firefox */
text-align-last: center; /* para chrome */
```

Comment: Funcionou! Sabe se no Safari vai centralizar?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Provavelmente não. Pelo que entendi não é algo ainda 100% possível sem auxílio de plugins.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado, Leon!