# Como retirar a seta padrão(do navegador) na tag select?

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um *< select >* personalizável. O problema são as diferentes renderizações que acontecem nos navegadores.
De fato, precisaria apenas ocultar as setas que aparecem:

no IE:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e no FF:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No Chrome e no Opera elas se ocultaram(Mesmo motor de renderização).

Obrigado!

Comment: Parece-me que a pergunta é parecida com esta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603979/select-removing-dropdown-arrow

Comment: Estilizar `<select>` é complicado, ele se comporta diferente em cada navegador, para isso eu uso o plugin FancySelect http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Nesse gist](https://gist.github.com/joaocunha/6273016/) há diversas propostas para resolver esse bug [reportado há muito tempo atrás](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849). Me lembro de ter utilizado a propriedade `moz-appearance:none` alguns meses atrás e ter funcionado, fui criar um exemplo para responder essa pergunta e... SURPRESA, deixou de funcionar nas atualizações recentes do Firefox.

#### 1ª Proposta

Criar um elemento elemento pai com largura definida e `overflow:hidden` (para esconder o que ultrapassar o limite). E, no `select`, definir uma largura maior que a do elemento pai. Por exemplo:

```css
.select {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /*para "contornar" o select*/
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px
}

.select > select {
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 110% /* 10% para esconder a seta :) */
}
```

```html
<span class='select'>
    <select>
        <option disabled selected>Selecione um destino</option>
        <option>São Paulo</option>
        <option>Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option>Tangamandapio</option>
    </select>
</span>
```

#### 2ª Proposta

Outra alternativa é criar um componente personalizado e isso não tem uma forma correta de ser feito, cada desenvolvedor fará do jeito que melhor lhe convém. Mas segue um exemplo que consegui utilizando <s>muita gambiarra</s> [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) para alterar a seta padrão e `z-index` para controlar o posicionamento dos elementos:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box
}

/* Esconder no IE 10 */
select::-ms-expand {
  display: none 
}

/* Outros navegadores */
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/* Caixa em volta do select */
.select {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1
}

/* A seta */
.select:before { 
  display: block;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  width: 1em;
  z-index: -1
}

.select > select {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Pseudo-class 'any', referência:
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:any */
:-moz-any(.select):before {
  background-color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

/**
 * O código abaixo não tem relevância, o único propósito
 * é tornar o exemplo 'apresentável' esteticamente. */
.select {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 0 2em;
  padding: 0;
}

.select:hover {
  border-color: #333;
}

.select:before {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 0.625em;
  text-align: center;
}

.select > select {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>

<div class='select fa-caret-down'>
    <select name=''>
        <option selected disabled>Esporte Favorito</option>
        <option>Basquete</option>
        <option>Futebol</option>
        <option>Volei</option>
        <option>Outro</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### 3ª Proposta (a melhor)

<s>Na minha opinião</s> A melhor coisa a se fazer até o momento (i.e. enquanto não é possível garantir que a regra do CSS vai afetar a aparência do `select`) é utilizar um plugin que garanta exibir o mesmo resultado independente do *browser* do usuário, como por exemplo:

[JQuery SelectBox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)
[Custom Select](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/)
[SelectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/)
[FancySelect](http://jquery-plugins.net/fancyselect-jquery-plugin-for-custom-select-box)

[Essa página](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/selectbox/) possui vários outros plugins para o mesmo propósito.

Answer (score 2):

```
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Remove estilo padrão do Chrome */
-moz-appearance: none; /* Remove estilo padrão do FireFox */
appearance: none; /* Remove estilo padrão do FireFox*/
```

Comment: 1) Não é necessário declarar sem o prefixo referente ao navegador: `appearance: none;`; 2) Não funciona no IE (nem é navegador tb); Vide [guia de compatibilidade caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance).