# mousedown em select Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

No momento do *click* em uma `<div>` o `<select>` deve abrir.

Dessa forma consigo abrir o `<select>`.

```js
$('.teste').click(function(){
  var element = $('#select')[0];
  var ev = new MouseEvent('mousedown');
  element.dispatchEvent(ev);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<div class="teste">Aperte-me</div>
```

O código porém não funciona no Firefox.

O mais incrível é que [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) documenta `MouseEvent`.

Como consigo fazer `mousedown` sobre um `<select>` no Firefox?

Comment: Abrir selects programáticamente é um pesadelo, usa um custom select, sabes como fazer?

Comment: Não, não sei como fazer.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46056/129

Comment: Sim, tinha visto esta pergunta e estava usando uma das soluções apresentadas para o meu `<select>`, porém o texto dentro dele era grande demais e encavalava no ícone do `:before`. Usei o `:before` num `<span>` e consegui formatar o `<select>` para o Firefox também.